# Entity framework core TPH query across different subtype properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF core TPH inheritance to model some data and I'm trying to write a query that will query across different subtypes. My current attempt at writing a query cannot be translated to SQL at run time of the query.

```
public class NameChange : Change {
    public string NewName {get; set;}
}

public class AddressChange : Change {
    public string NewAddress {get; set;}
}

public class Change {
    public long Id {get; set;}
}
```

Query:

```
        var changes = _context.Changes.Where(x => 
            (x as NameChange).NewName == "john" ||
            (x as AddressChange).NewAddress== "123 street").ToList();
```

This query gives me an InvalidOperationException, is there a way to rewrite it so that I am able to write a single query that will query across different subtype properties? If not then I question if I should be using TPH at all. I am using EF Core version 3.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way I was casting was not supported with my version of EFCore (facepalm). This code snippet works

```
var changes = _context.Changes.Where(x => 
            ((NameChange)x).NewName == "john" ||
            ((AddressChange)x).NewAddress== "123 street").ToList();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).